# cycle2 does not trigger cycle-finished event

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

having trouble getting cycle-finished to trigger. does anyone see what is wrong with this

http://jsfiddle.net/aQe8X/

```
   <html>
<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p1.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p2.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p3.jpg">
    <img src="http://malsup.github.io/images/p4.jpg">
</div>


<script>
        $('.cycle-slideshow').on('cycle-finished', function(event, opts ) {
            alert ("done");
        });

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: answer: cycle-finished needs loop to be on... this works<html>

<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-loop="1">

Comment: Thanks! But you could also have chosen to answer you own question instead of putting the answer in a comment.